# Can I Copy the whole admin panel to my custom panel or page

Tags: magento-2.1, php, multi-vendor, vendor

I am new to **Magento** and I am using the **Magento 2**, my question is:
Is there any way to copy the whole admin panel or functionalities to my custom panel or page?
suggest me a solution.I want to create a user with admin capabilities but not all features.